# Showing the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and determining its Galois group.

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension. I would like to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})/\mathbb{Q}$ is the splitting field of $f(x) = x^6 - 3$ which is irreducible by Eisenstein. If $\zeta_6 = e^{\pi i/3}$, then the roots of $f(x)$ are $\zeta_6^k\sqrt[6]{3}$ for $0 \leq k < 6$. I was able to show that $\zeta_6 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})$ because $\zeta_6 = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ (depending on the choice of root of $-1$ chosen). How would I show that $\sqrt[6]{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})$ using this? From there, I would be able to deduce that all the roots of $f(x)$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})$.

As for the Galois group, because $f(x)$ is irreducible, we must have that this is a field extension of degree 6 so the Galois group is either isomorphic to $S_3$ or $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. How would I determine which group it is? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: It should be $x^6+3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are looking at $x^6 - 3$ instead of $x^6 + 3$. I shall look at the latter.

---

For concreteness, fix $F = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{3}\iota)$, where $\iota$ is an imaginary root of $-1$. (Note that $(\sqrt[6]{3}\iota)^6$ is indeed $-3$.)

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[6]{3}\iota$. Then, $\alpha^3 = -\iota\sqrt{2}$ and thus, $\zeta_6 := \exp(2\pi\iota/6) \in F$.

Note that $\zeta_6^k\alpha$ are roots of $x^6 \color{red}{+} 3$. Thus, $F$ contains all the roots of $x^6 + 3$ and hence, is its splitting field (being generated by one of them).

In particular, it is Galois.

---

Now, to compute the Galois group, we see what are the isomorphisms $F \to F$ (which fix $\Bbb Q$, but this happens automatically).

Consider $\sigma_i : F \to F$ defined by $\alpha \mapsto \zeta_6^i \alpha$ for $i = 0, \ldots, 5$.
(Does it make sense why we can do this?)

<strike>Now, it is easy to see that $\sigma_0, \ldots, \sigma_5$ are distinct (and thus, we have found all) and the composition makes it clear that the Galois group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z$.</strike>

Looking at the image of $\alpha$ under the above maps shows that $\sigma_0, \ldots, \sigma_5$ are distinct. However, the group is *not* isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$. It may be tempting (it certainly was, for me) to think that $$\color{red}{\sigma_i(\sigma_j(\alpha)) = \zeta_6^{i + j} \alpha}$$
but the equation above is $\color{red}{\text{not true}}$ in general since $\sigma_i$ need not fix $\zeta_6$. (Thanks to [leoli1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/649658/leoli1) for pointing this out!)

---

Let us show that there are two elements of order $2$.
$\sigma_3$ clearly has order $2$ since $$\sigma_3(\sigma_3(\alpha)) = \sigma_3(\zeta_6^3\alpha) = \sigma_3(-\alpha) = -\zeta_6^3\alpha = \alpha.$$

We now show that $\sigma_1$ also has order $2$. For this, we do some calculations. First, note that $\zeta_6 = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \alpha^3).$ Thus, we have $$\sigma_1(\alpha) = \zeta_6\alpha = \frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{\alpha^4}{2}.$$
Applying $\sigma_1$ again gives
\begin{align}
\sigma_1(\sigma_1(\alpha)) &= \frac{\zeta_6\alpha}{2} - \frac{\zeta_6^4\alpha^4}{2} \\ 
&= \frac{\zeta_6\alpha}{2} + \frac{\zeta_6\alpha^4}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \alpha \zeta_6 (1 + \alpha^3) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \alpha \frac{1}{2}(1 - \alpha^3)(1 + \alpha^3) \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{4}(1 - \alpha^6) = \alpha.
\end{align}

Thus, the Galois group cannot be $\Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z$. This leaves us only with $S_3$.

Comment: You're right, I should have been looking at $x^6 + 3$! As for the $\sigma_i$, this can be done because the Galois group acts transitively on the roots of $x^6 + 3$, right? And lastly, why is it easy to see that the five automorphisms you have written down are distinct? Can you give me a hint as to how I can see this?

Comment: 1. It can be done because of the following general phenomenon: Suppose $E/F$ is an extension of fields and $\alpha \in E$ is algebraic over $F$. Then, you can define a field homomorphism $F(\alpha) \to E$ which fixes $F$ by mapping $\alpha$ to any root of its irreducible polynomial. (No assumption of Galois-ness anywhere.) In our case, we have that $x^6 + 3$ is irreducible (by Eisenstein) and thus, what I've given actually defines a map. $$$$ 2. It is indeed easy to see why they are distinct. Simply look at where $\alpha$ goes under them! :-)

Comment: Both your points makes sense, thanks so much! :)

Comment: The Galois group is *not* isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ (note that not all $\sigma_i$ fix $\zeta_6$)

Comment: @leoli1: Thanks a lot. Fixed it. Did you have any easier way of seeing that it is not $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Nino: Please make note that my earlier answer was incorrect.

Comment: I thought about proving $\sigma_1\sigma_2\ne\sigma_2\sigma_1$, but the calculations for this are almost the same as in your answer, so its not really easier. Another (less elementary) approach is to consider the field tower $\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q(\zeta_6)/\Bbb Q$. From this we get a short exact sequence of Galois groups. One can show that this splits and we get a description of $G(\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q)$ as a semi-direct product of the smaller Galois groups. Computing these then shows us that the big group is isomorphic to $S_3$. This idea also generalizes to other 'Kummer-like' situations.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Thank you for clarifying! I actually also found that it is straightforward to show that $\sigma_1(\sigma_3(\alpha)) \neq \sigma_3(\sigma_1(\alpha))$ for if this were true, $-\zeta_6\alpha = -\sigma_3(\zeta_6)\alpha$ implying that $\sigma_3(\zeta_6) = \zeta_6$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Nino: And why is that a contradiction? Are you using $\zeta_6 = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \alpha^3)$? Or is there something simpler that I'm missing?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Wouldn't this be a contradiction because this would imply that $\sigma_3$ fixes an element not in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Nino: No, that alone not a contradiction. In fact, since $\sigma_3$ generates a subgroup of order $2$, it fixes a subfield $E \subset F$ which is a degree $3$ extension of $\Bbb Q$. In particular, it fixes many elements outside $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Nino: What you might be thinking about is the following: If $a \in F$ is fixed by **all** $\sigma_i$, then $a$ must be in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I see, thank you for clarifying that for me! :)

Comment: @leoli1, you 2nd idea seems advanced one but interesting. Any reference for that ?